# What version is my VS 2005 Web Site project?

Tags: web, visual-studio-2005, vs-web-site-project

I thought this would be simpler to verify, but I haven't been in VS 2005 for quite some time. I have a web site (not *web application*) project I'm trying to troubleshoot some errors in and I want to verify the .net run-time version.

The only hint I've found is in the references section of the property pages. There is a reference to System.Windows.Forms v 2.0.0.0. Is this my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is, but check your `Web.config` file.  Since a web site has no .vbproj file, `Web.config` is the only relevant file here.  This is where VS stores the references that you see in the property pages.

Comment: good enough for me. I have verified that production is running .net 2